# CSS Animations stall when running javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

Let's say I have this javascript function:

```
   function pauseComp(ms) {
     var date = new Date();
     var curDate = null;
     do { curDate = new Date(); }
     while(curDate-date < ms);
    }
```

and a css3 animation (for instance, `<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i>` from the new [font-awesome 3](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#examples)). When I run the javascript function above, it stops the spinner while the function is running. **See what I'm talking about [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JU4St/1/)**. Basically, javascript stops css animations, and I'm wondering why, or if anyone else has noticed this/found a workaround. I've tried putting it in a setTimeout(fn,0), where fn is the long process, but then realized why that will also not work (js is not multithreaded). Anyone seen this happening?

Update: Interestingly, it looks like this isn't as much of a problem in Safari, although interaction with the browser interface is still being affected.

Comment: You'll need to break your "long running code" up into chunks to allow everything else to continue.

Comment: Right, though I am aware that this would fix it, that's not a viable solution for the functions I'm trying to apply this to. The functions are not breakable into smaller chunks. I am really checking to see if anyone has a solution for the exact problem above, which, likewise, cannot be broken up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A browser page is single threaded. Updating the UI happens on the same thread as your javascript program.  Which also means that any animation will not draw new frames while Javascript code is being executed. Typically, this is no big deal because most JS code is executed very quickly, faster than a single animation frame.

So the best advice is simply this: Don't do that. Don't lock up the JS engine for that long. Figure out a cleaner way to do it.

---

However, if you must, there is a way.  You can get an additional thread via [HTML5's Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers). This isn't supported in older browsers, but it will allow you to run some long running CPU sucking code away from the main webpage and in it's own thread, and then have it post back some result to your page when it's done.

Comment: Yes, I've seen web workers. Do you know if web workers have access to the DOM? Because my long-running process is all DOM updates happening in jQuery, and that's what's slow.

Comment: @ChristianBankester Web Workers cannot access the DOM. You'll have to use `setTimeout`.

Comment: Ah, I have tried using setTimeout, which did not work. See this updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JU4St/2/

Comment: Also, I understand that this is the nature of javascript, being single-threaded and all. Just wondering if there *is* a fix that will accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: Combining `setTimeout` with your `pauseComp` won't work. You have to do split your time-consuming operation in chunks, and and call a chunk at a time using `setTimeout`.

Comment: `setTimeout` does _not_ spawn a new thread. It simply schedules a function to be called on the main thread later on. When called, it will still block.  If all you want to do is schedule some called to be called later, and that code runs fast, all you need is `setTimeout(someFn, 3000)`.  You will only need a worker thread if you are doing some sort of very CPU intensive calcuation.