# Is it true that GIF animation runs on the same thread as javascript in all mainstream browsers?

Tags: javascript, ajax, animated-gif

I show an animated GIF that runs while my AJAX request is in progress and gets stopped once my script has processed the response.

While this works, I notice that while the response from the request is being processed in my script (which contains some fairly heavy updating of the DOM) the animation freezes.

My research leads me to believe that this is because the animation of the GIF happens on the same thread that javascript is running on - that the browser is truly single-threaded. Is this the correct interpretation for all current mainstream browsers (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE)?

Secondly, why is it done this way? Is it really not possible that the browser could dedicate a thread to GIF animations so they didn't freeze when a block of javascript was being executed?

**Update**

[This](http://www.phpied.com/css-animations-off-the-ui-thread/) is an interesting page. It talks about using pure CSS3 animations. They still freeze in Firefox though - maybe soon FF will fix this. Looks like I should be considering CSS for animation rather that using a GIF.

Comment: Shouldn't this be easy to check? Pull up the web inspector, set a breakpoint. My guess is no, but if it actually is, maybe it will help convince people to stop using gifs, in which case, maybe it shouldn't be fixed...

Comment: Well yes, setting a breakpoint stops the animated GIF from running. So, what is your alternative to an animated GIF then?

Comment: I don't have one *myself*, and there does not appear to be a format widely supported in client software that even matches the stability of the horrific quality of GIF, but you must know that the GIF format itself (and all known software that renders it) is horribly outdated. GIF collectively robs us of many many gigawatts, i'd wager. And also runs dog-slow for any non trivial resolution on mobile devices

Comment: Unknown to many people, but PNG can be animated as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG

Comment: There are also CSS3 animations, though not sure what thread they happen to run on... (e.g. `icon-spin` from "font awesome")

Comment: interestingly enough: FF [suffers from it](http://jsfiddle.net/aFB7J/2/) but chrome doesn't. Can't test IE because it's CSS3 and I refuse to install v10.

Comment: @Brad - I did my testing in Chrome (v 25.0.1364.172) and it suffers from the problem - though Chrome now tells me it needs updating. I'll give that a go and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Interesting - I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367168/css-animations-stall-when-running-javascript-function which seems to have the same problem, but using pure CSS3 animations. His fiddle works nicely in Chrome, but freezes the animation in FF (v 21.0).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problme is (IMHO) that when you update the dom the browser do not repaint the page, so the image freeze.

Try to do heavy thing without change dom, the gif should animate (slowly if your cpu is busy) but not freeze.

If it freeze anyway you could explicitly create a new thread for that work (using webworker) but if i remember right you could not change dom form a webworker.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably well known by now, but CSS3 has it's own thread in most modern browsers.  You should be able to set a breakpoint in javascript and still see your css animation running.  Check out this link to see how to animate a sprite with pure css:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps